# Add a LinearLayout below ListView

Tags: android, listview

Actually it's not ListView but ExpandableListView but it doesn't really matter. Normally I'd do it this way:

```
<ScrollView >

<LinearLayout>
    <ExpandableListView ... />
    <TextView ... />        
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

..but I've read it's consuming to have ListView inside ScrollView. I tried solving this by modifying ExpandListAdapter (getChildView()) :

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(isLastChild){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra_info_bottom, null);

        }
        else{
                 //get normal item view
        }
        return view;
}
```

but this way I can only append childs to groups. How can I append LinearLayout on the bottom outside of any group?

Comment: check which `LayoutParams` import in your package ?

Comment: Actually I've got that previous error because of syntax mistake. Please review my answer (last paragraph)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the following code to add the a linear layout at the last listview block.

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
                itemlist.addFooterView(footerView);
```

where the listfooter is the xml file where you can define your layout controlls.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you want to have the listview inside the scroll?? wouldn't make sense for your layout to do something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ExpandableListView ... />
    <ScrollView >
      <LinearLayout>
         <TextView ... />   
      </LinearLayout>     
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

With this solution you can use weights on the Expandable List and the Scrollview to define how much of the screen you want to use for the List and how much for the linear layout at the bottom.

If you want your linear layout to appear at the very bottom of the list, I would suggest you to use a footer instead of the getView thing.

Anyway, to help with the exact issue you have, I would need to look at the xml definition of what you are trying to inflate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out what object does cause this error and look for it's real className using `myObject.getClass().getName()`. So you can see what object you really inflated and maybe fix the problem.

Comment: Actually I've got that previous error because of syntax mistake. Please review my answer (last paragraph)!